# UI5 parameters: data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme and data-sap-ui-xx-componentpreload

Tags: sapui5, ui5-tooling

The UI5 HTML-bootstrapper has two parameters which I don't really understand:

- `data-sap-ui-xx-componentpreload`
- `data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme`

I've checked the official documentation and didn't get some straightforward description.

My questions:

1. When should I use `data-sap-ui-xx-componentpreload` and what are its benefits?
2. When should I use `data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme` and what are its benefits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### ⚠️ First things first ...

**`xx-` options are experimental.** They may be removed in future UI5 versions or their behavior may change in an incompatible way.

### Option `sap-ui-xx-componentPreload`

By default, UI5 requests the app **bundle** `Component-preload.js` automatically when creating ComponentContainer (e.g. via `data-sap-ui-oninit="module:sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport"`).

[The bundle is generated by UI5 tooling for deployment](https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling/pages/Configuration/#component-preload-generation) so that users finally use the **optimized version** of the app. Therefore, **avoid shipping the standalone app with `data-sap-ui-xx-componentpreload` in `index.html`!** Otherwise, users will end up using unnecessarily the unminified, unbundled developer version of the app.

Options in `index.html` (`data-sap-ui-*`) don't affect typical Fiori launchpad (FLP) apps as FLP uses its own HTML page.

Using `sap-ui-xx-componentPreload` makes only sense for previewing, testing, or demo scenarios where there is no Node.js environment (unable to use UI5 tooling) so that 404-errors can be avoided. SAP Web IDE, for example, used to append the option `sap-ui-xx-componentPreload=off` in the URL so that the preview runs without the 404-error.

#### Values

- `async` or `sync` by default depending on the `sap-ui-preload` / `sap-ui-async` settings.
- `off` to load `Component.js` instead of `Component-preload.js` despite having a ComponentContainer.

### Option `sap-ui-xx-waitForTheme`

The `xx-waitForTheme` option helps to avoid FOUC (Flash Of Unstyled Content) and, in some cases, to reduce sync XHRs. The option tells the app to postpone certain tasks until the theme has been loaded and applied.

#### Values (since UI5 1.63)

- `init` waits for the theme → executes Core's init handler (`attachInit(fn)`) → renders the app.
  Use this if some controls try to access theme-dependent parameters via [`sap/ui/core/theming/Parameters.get` synchronously (deprecated)](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/73cebd8e91a546ee952f3873657eb4783e1130bb) too soon.
- `rendering` (formerly `true` until 1.62) executes Core's init handler first → waits for the theme → initializes the rendering.

If there is no value set, Core's init and initial rendering are executed immediately without waiting for the theme → FOUC.

---

For more options and information, see [Configuration Options and URL Parameters](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/91f2d03b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070) and its parent topics.

Comment: PS: the description for `xx-waitForTheme` in the doc isn't updated after https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/463a5cee6c1002050ff603c0a279c56d105a22e2

Comment: _«the description for xx-waitForTheme in the doc isn't updated after»_ — Should be an issue opened in Github?

Comment: @MikeB. When `init` was introduced, I had the impression that it's not ready, too new, or not worth changing the doc (the commit title starts with `[INTERNAL]`). Not sure but you could try. :) Maybe they just forgot

Comment: Boghyon, done: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3335

Comment: BTW, regarding of possible values of `xx-waitForTheme`, according to documentation it's a `boolean` and therefore can receive only `true`/`false`, rather than `init`/`rendering`.

Comment: @MikeB. That was what I was actually referring to. The documentation isn't updated after https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/463a5cee6c1002050ff603c0a279c56d105a22e2. The values used to be boolean (`true`/`false`) but after the commit, the option now awaits a string value: `init` or `rendering` (with `rendering` behaving same as `true` for compatibility reasons). Check the source code in the commit. The doc is outdated.

Comment: OK, now I got you correctly. I've updated the issue.

Comment: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3335 is fixed!

Comment: @Mike https://github.com/SAP/openui5-docs/commit/0f8167f5cbdfa7610387f14cf8532857bb3cb739 - the fix should be live tomorrow on https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/topic/91f2d03b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070